# Excel - Highlight Lowest Price in Each Row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight the lowest price in each row for a price comparison spreadsheet. I have been having trouble using conditional formatting and wonder if there is a macro and VBA that does the job. Can someone help me on how to highlight the lowest price in each row excluding cells with values of "0" or blank. Thank you so much!

-The spreadsheet goes from column A to P

-Column C,F,I,L,O are the prices.

-Some price cells do not have a value and are displayed as "$ - " in accounting format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No VBA required:

Copy and paste the following into the Name Box (upper-left corner of Excel):

```
C:C,F:F,I:I,L:L,O:O
```

And the press the `Enter` key.

This will select those columns.

Now click on the Home tab of the Ribbon and then click on:

```
Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format
```

In the textbox that reads `Format values where this formula is true` enter:

```
=C1=MIN(IF($C1=0,2E+99,$C1),IF($F1=0,2E+99,$F1),IF($I1=0,2E+99,$I1),IF($L1=0,2E+99,$L1),IF($O1=0,2E+99,$O1))
```

Finally, click the `Format` button to select the color you want and then confirm.

Comment: For me, it didn't disregard zero values and selected them as the lowest.

Comment: @Variatus Ahh. I misread the OP question and coded for BLANKS. I've updated the my answer to handle ZEROS as well now.

Comment: Did this answer work for you, Genn Zhong?

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for what I am working on!

Comment: Please select my answer by clicking on the checkmark directly to the left of my answer.

Comment: Got it! Can you do me one more favor by telling me what the if statement is doing in this case?

Comment: With Excel formulas it can be difficult to get the minimum from a group of numbers while excluding ZEROs... because a zero is less than any number (assuming the group does not contain negative numbers). The typical way to achieve that is to use a formula based on the SMALL and FREQUENCY functions... but this will not work in your case because the range for the is split over several column and UNION range references are not allowed in Conditional Formatting. So we have to remove the ZEROs and BLANKs by brute force. Continued...

Comment: Your requirement includes five columns and for each we use an IF function to temporarily transform a current ZERO from any of those fives columns into a massive number: `2E99` This is larger than any number you will ever use in Excel. The result is that all ZEROs are transformed from the smallest number to the largest number and then MIN can easily return the smallest, non-zero number in the group.